# How can we use cedar wood for the Beis Hamikdosh?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, masechet-taanis

We know that some of the Beis Hamikdosh was built with ארז aka cedar wood. But how does this fit with the statement in Taanis that we should strive to be as pliant as a reed and not as firm as a cedar? This statement and the subsequent story of rabbi Shimon seem to cast a negative light on cedar trees, saying that they’re stubborn and lack roots and, symbolically, don’t listen to different opinions and whatnot. So how can a tree like this be used to build the Beis Hamikdosh??

Comment: Everything has its place ...

Comment: I don't get this question. What does a metaphor for our human traits have to do with top quality building materials? Besides, Shlomo called Hashem בחור כארזים, A youth like cedar trees. Shir Hashirim 5:15.

Answer (score -1):

The righteous shall flourish like a date palm, he shall grow like a cedar in Lebanon

This psalm outranks your Gemara, so the top contenders are date palm and cedar. Had they used date palm, the would have had to chop so many down it would jeopardize the lulav supply so they went with cedar. Also, cedar is rot resistant and repels bugs.

Comment: Although without an explanation it merely shifts the question back, since the authors of the Talmud knew Tehillim